# Android set text clickable programmatically

Tags: android, parsing, textview

I have an arbitrary string of text. What I'd like to do, Is for any substring of text which indicates some kind of duration, i.e. 5 minutes, 5:00, 1/2 hour, half an hour, etc, I would like to make the text clickable, opening an imageview which when clicked will lead the user to a timer set at the respective time, counting down.

However, I need to figure out how to do this programatically. I have done quite a bit of research, and the vast majority of solutions out there seem to be designed specifically for emails or URLs. I have looked into some kind of regex matching, but I can't figure out how to tell the onclicklistener which specific part of the text was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
yourTextView.performClick()
```

> Call this view's OnClickListener, if it is defined. Performs all
>   normal actions associated with clicking: reporting accessibility
>   event, playing a sound, etc.

or another choice is

```
yourTextView.callOnClick ()
```

> Directly call any attached OnClickListener. Unlike performClick(),
>   this only calls the listener, and does not do any associated clicking
>   actions like reporting an accessibility event.

But it be added in API level 15

hope this helps

Comment: how would I know which section of text has been clicked?